# In the sentence "ls -Ral /bin > TalhaA452.txt"

Tags: command-line, ls, nano

what does -Ral do? I dont know what this word means in the sentence "ls -Ral  /bin > TalhaA452.txt"

Comment: RTFM.. `man ls`

Answer (score 3):

This command list directory contents of `bin` folder and put contents in a file called `TalhaA452.txt`

According to `man ls`, the switches do:

-R, --recursive

```
list subdirectories recursively
```

-a, --all

```
do not ignore entries starting with .
```

-l

```
use a long listing format
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man ls`

```
-a, --all
              do not ignore entries starting with .
-R, --recursive
              list subdirectories recursively
-l     use a long listing format
```

It means that it will generate a list of all files under `/bin` recussively going in sub-directories and save that list in the `TalhaA452.txt` text file.